# Display different login page based on requirements in Phonegap android apps?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

My Phonegap application login page contains a few input fields like username, password, url, device type, etc... that the user has to enter to activate the application when he logins for the fist time. The next time on the user has to enter only the username and password as the application is already activated. So I want to display only the username and password fields the second time on login.

I have a phonegap plugin to check whether the app is activated or not. I want to call this plugin and based on the callback response I will show only necessary fields on the login page.So what would be the easiest way to do this?

I tried this..

```
$("#loginPage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
window.plugins.AuthPlugin.appIsActive(appIsActiveCallBack);
});
function appIsActiveCallBack(result){//Show only relative fields...}
```

But I got this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appIsActive' of undefined

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `Uncaught TypeError` because you are trying to call the plugin before even the device is ready... Call the Plugin only when the device is ready...

**UPDATE**

What you have to do is to determine what all fields you need to show in native side only...
After that pass a variable(flag) from java to JavaScript which will be accessible at **pagebeforeshow**

So your Activity will look like something like this

```
/*
 * Some database operations which you need to check 
 *  so that you can determine what to show
 */
this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 20000);
super.loadUrl("javascript: { var pageFlag = '" + flag + "';}");
```

And in your **index.html** show like this

```
$("#loginPage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
alert(pageFlag);
});
```

After that with the use of flag you can determine what to show and what not to...

Hope it helps...

Comment: If i call the plugin when device is ready,by that time login page(i.e first page of app) with all fields will be displayed and after getting callback i have to hide unnecessary displayed fields and that's annoying.so i was thinking to call plugin first ,get response and then based on that change my login page on load

Comment: Yes for that you need to do something else...Do you want to know how?

Comment: Obviously..I want to know that..will be highly thankful if you spend some time here to explain.